# Wildfly Apache Spark - Application not getting deployed Could not build ClassFile

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, wildfly-10, apache-phoenix

I am trying to deploy a web application which has dependencies on Spark version 2.1.1, Hbase 1.2, Phoenix 4.11 and Kafka 0.9.

The application is not getting deployed, the error I am encountering is given below.
It is regarding javassist, the default javassist (v 3.18.0-Final) shipped with wildfly is being referred to here.

```
16:37:09,171 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."client.war#DefaultTenant".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."client.war#DefaultTenant".__FIRST_PHASE__: org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:104)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:47)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.VirtualFileSystemArchiveDescriptor.processVirtualFile(VirtualFileSystemArchiveDescriptor.java:94)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.VirtualFileSystemArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(VirtualFileSystemArchiveDescriptor.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:40)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.<init>(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:39)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:199)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$900(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
    ... 7 more

16:37:09,191 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "client.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"client.war#DefaultTenant\".__FIRST_PHASE__" => "org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile"}}
```